# Prettier extension not wokring onsave on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

Summary
when I run prettier from the command line it's working fine, but when I open vscode prettier it's not working.

NOTE: I do have prettier working in Windows in the same project and formatter works fine onsave. The problem is when i run the same project on ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have format on save enabled in your workspace?

Comment: @Berk Kurkcuoglu Yes of course